# How can I add/subtract vectors by Calc in Org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, calc

I want to add/subtract two vectors, X and Y in Calc.

If I `calc` **constant numerics** within Org-mode source block, it's o.k.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc :session *Calculator*
[1,1] + [2,2] + [3,3]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: [6, 6]

#+BEGIN_SRC calc :session *Calculator*
[3,3] - [2,2] - [1,1]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: [0, 0]

#+BEGIN_SRC calc :session *Calculator*
[1,10,100] * [10,100,1000]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 101010
```

Applying Calc within Emacs Lisp source code block in Org-mode is o.k.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results value scalar :exports both
(setq X '[1 2])
(setq Y '[3 4])
(calc-eval (format "%s+%s" X Y))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: "[4, 6]"
```

On the other hands, If I try in Calc source block with **variables** , it fails.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc :var X=[1 2], Y=[3 4]
X+Y
#+END_SRC

# (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p [1 2])
```

Add can be done strangely with further extra brackets,

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc :var X=[1 2], Y=[3 4]
[X]+[Y]
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: [[4, 6]]
```

but fails in subtraction.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc :var X=[1 2], Y=[3 4]
[X]-[Y]
#+END_SRC
# (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p [3 4])
```

How can I add/subtract vectors by Calc in Org-mode source code block ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about the actual reason plus won't work the way you expect, but this is what Calc does when you add vectors interactively:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC calc :var X=[1 2], Y=[3 4]
  map(add, X, Y)
#+END_SRC
```

The result where you get `[[4, 6]]` seems to indicate that Calc needs vectors to be 2D matrices with a single column, rather than 1D matrices.

Comment: I thank you for your help!
Thank you for your great answer !

Comment: @RUserPassingBy sure, you are welcome! :)

Comment: where does this `map` function comes from? is it a calc function? 
How do I call it from a calc buffer?

Comment: @JeniaIvanov this would be `V M` if you wanted to call this interactively (it will prompt you for a function to map with.

Comment: @wvxvw thanks a lot. How do I apply arbitrary calc command in a src block? `#+BEGIN_SRC calc [1, 2]
[2,3]
'+
#+END_SRC`
Doesn't work. It work if the two values on the stack are numbers though.

Comment: @JeniaIvanov you would really need to look into Calc manual. Normally, and interactive command would be associated with a Calc function. The best place I can think to look for examples would be the Org mode table formulas, they use Calc language.

Comment: #+BEGIN_SRC calc :session *Calculator*\n
[1 2] + [2 3]\n
#+END_SRC\n
Ah, You must change lines by [Return](invisible \n), which is not applicable in this comment area.